# Unable to remove IIS 7 completely

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

I faced some issues in loading COM component through a WebService because the user hadn't permission for `C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\schema` folder. When I opened the file using Windows Explorer, it has changed the permission and added Users group and the current user to access the folder. This has solved my issue but I need isolate this to confirm.

I tried removing IIS from the box (including the management console). But `C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\` folder exists and being used by SMSvchost and svchost within the system how can I completely remove the IIS from my system? I believe a reinstall would help to restore the old privileges back to the `C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\schema` folder and files. I think the folder requires permission from "Trusted Installers" group.

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 in my box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using buit-in takeown and cacls utilities.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-delete-a-system-file-in-windows-vista/